# Why is this not correct? (codeeval challenge)PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is what I have to do https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/140/

I've been on this challenge for three days, please help. It it is 85-90 partially solved. But not 100% solved... why?

This is my code:

```
import sys
test_cases = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')
for test in test_cases:
    saver=[]
    text=""
    textList=[]
    positionList=[]
    num=0
    exists=int()
    counter=0
    for l in test.strip().split(";"):
        saver.append(l)
    for i in saver[0].split(" "):
        textList.append(i)
    for j in saver[1].split(" "):
        positionList.append(j)

    for i in range(0,len(positionList)):
        positionList[i]=int(positionList[i])

    accomodator=[None]*len(textList)

    for n in range(1,len(textList)):
        if n not in positionList:
            accomodator[n]=textList[len(textList)-1]
            exists=n       

    for item in positionList:
        accomodator[item-1]=textList[counter]
        counter+=1
        if counter>item:
            accomodator[exists-1]=textList[counter]

    for word in accomodator:
            text+=str(word) + " "
    print text
test_cases.close()
```

Comment: Try replacing `.split(';')` with `.rsplit(';',1)`. If I were designing the test, I'd have an input line with an extra `;` in it.

Comment: I did it and it still says it is partially solved... I dont understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
import sys


def main(name_file):
    _file = open(name_file, 'r')
    text = ""
    while True:
        try:
            line = _file.next()
            disordered_line, numbers_string = line.split(';')
            numbers_list = map(int, numbers_string.strip().split(' '))
            missing_number = sum(xrange(sorted(numbers_list)[0],sorted(numbers_list)[-1]+1)) - sum(numbers_list)
            if missing_number == 0:
                missing_number = len(disordered_line)
            numbers_list.append(missing_number)
            disordered_list = disordered_line.split(' ')
            string_position = zip(disordered_list, numbers_list)
            ordered = sorted(string_position, key = lambda x: x[1])
            text +=  " ".join([x[0] for x in ordered])
            text += "\n"
        except StopIteration:
            break
    _file.close()
    print text.strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

I'll try to explain my code step by step  so maybe you can see the difference between your code and mine one:

```
while True
```

A loop that breaks when  there are no more lines.

```
try:
```

I put the code inside a try and catch the StopIteracion exception, because this is raised when there are no more items in a generator.

```
line = _file.next()
```

Use a generator, so that way you do not put all the lines in memory from once.

```
disordered_line, numbers_string = line.split(';')
```

Get the unordered phrase and the numbers of every string's position.

```
numbers_list = map(int, numbers_string.strip().split(' '))
```

Convert every number from `string` to `int`

```
missing_number = sum(xrange(sorted(numbers_list)[0],sorted(numbers_list)[-1]+1)) - sum(numbers_list)
```

Get the missing number from the serial of numbers, so that missing number is the position of the last string in the phrase.

```
if missing_number == 0:
    missing_number = len(unorder_line)
```

Check if the missing number is equal to 0 if so then the really missing number is equal to the number of the strings that make the phrase.

```
numbers_list.append(missing_number)
```

Append the missing number to the list of numbers.

```
disordered_list = disordered_line.split(' ')
```

Conver the disordered phrase into a list.

```
string_position = zip(disordered_list, numbers_list)
```

Combine every string with its respective position.

```
ordered = sorted(string_position, key = lambda x: x[1])
```

Order the combined list by the position of the string.

```
text +=  " ".join([x[0] for x in ordered])
```

Concatenate the ordered phrase, and the reamining code it's easy to understand.

**UPDATE**

By looking at your code here is my opinion tha might solve your problem.

`split` already returns a list so you do not have to loop over the splitted content to add that content to another list.

So these six lines:

```
for l in test.strip().split(";"):
    saver.append(l)
for i in saver[0].split(" "):
    textList.append(i)
for j in saver[1].split(" "):
    positionList.append(j)
```

can be converted into three:

```
splitted_test = test.strip().split(';')
textList = splitted_test[0].split(" ")
positionList = map(int, splitted_test[1].split(" "))
```

In this line `positionList = map(int, splitted_test[0].split(" "))` You already convert numbers into int, so you save these two lines:

```
for i in range(0,len(positionList)):
    positionList[i]=int(positionList[i])
```

The next lines:

```
accomodator=[None]*len(textList)

for n in range(1,len(textList)):
    if n not in positionList:
         accomodator[n]=textList[len(textList)-1]
         exists=n
```

can be converted into the next four:

```
missing_number = sum(xrange(sorted(positionList)[0],sorted(positionList)[-1]+1)) - sum(positionList)
if missing_number == 0:
    missing_number = len(textList)
    positionList.append(missing_number)
```

Basically what these lines do is calculate the missing number in the serie of numbers so the len of the serie is the same as `textList`.

The next lines:

```
for item in positionList:
    accomodator[item-1]=textList[counter]
    counter+=1
    if counter>item:
       accomodator[exists-1]=textList[counter]
for word in accomodator:
   text+=str(word) + " "
```

Can be replaced by these ones:

```
string_position = zip(textList, positionList) 
ordered = sorted(string_position, key = lambda x: x[1])
text +=  " ".join([x[0] for x in ordered])
text += "\n"
```

From this way you can save, lines and memory, also use [xrange](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#xrange-type) instead of `range`.

Maybe the factors that make your code pass partially could be:

1. Number of lines of the script
2. Number of time your script takes.
3. Number of memory your script uses.

What you could do is:

1. Use Generators. #You save memory
2. Reduce `for`'s, this way you save lines of code and time.
3. If you think something could be made it easier, do it.
4. Do not redo the wheel, if something has been already made it, use it.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer why the code in OP's question doesn't work perfectly. Perhaps you want to highlight the differences and what's missing in OP's code.

Comment: @justhalf What about now?

Comment: Hmm, better, but you only explain your code, not his code. His question is about his code. Just think of this question like this: imagine OP reads your answer and says "But that's exactly what I'm trying to do with my code! Do you know where I go wrong?" How would you answer that?

Comment: @justhalf I do not know where is his code wrong, because the webpage he gives to test the code, return that his code passed with 95% and does not tell you anymore, thats why I made my code and posted my answer.

Comment: @FutoFarai Read my comment above yours, and maybe you can try to make your code shorter and use generators.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres: The way to teach somebody is not always by "You got it wrong? Here is a correct code, learn from it", but also by "You got it wrong? Hmm, this line of your code is suspicious, perhaps it will fail in the case n=0?". You can make your answer better by doing the second one =)

Comment: @justhalf Thank you, I updated the answer maybe now I can help him :D

Comment: A correction: looping over a list returned by a function doesn't redo the function call, so it's perfectly fine to do `for l in test.strip().split(';'):`. Thanks for your update, it's definitely  better now that you have addressed some of the shortcomings of OP's code, but I think you haven't mentioned explicitly which part of his code is making the code solve the challenge only partially. Can you spot that?

Comment: @justhalf Yeah I forget it,Updated answer.

Comment: This whole thread illuminates why codeeval makes a poor learning tool.